# Using static lifetimes triggers "closure may outlive function" when self is borrowed inside a closure

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

My program uses the memory address of variables as a unique identifier. I know this is incredibly ugly, but it is a very lightweight way to get a unique identifier. **This pattern is only valid if I make these variables static so their unique id (i.e. address) lives "forever"** which means I have several functions which require a reference with a `'static` lifetime.

I'm using the [cortex-m crate](https://crates.io/crates/cortex-m) which provides a method which places the processor in a state that allows a function to run in an interrupt-free critical section. This is accomplished by a function which wraps the call to the function that needs to be executed in a critical section with the appropriate assembly calls.

In this contrived example, the wrapper function is called `run_in_special_state`. I need to execute the `foo` method in the special state. However, it requires a `'static Contrived`. Here's an example that  illustrates the error:

```
fn foo(_: &'static Contrived) {}

fn run_in_special_state<F, R>(f: F) -> R
where
    F: FnOnce() -> R,
{
    // Some stuff happens before the function
    let r = f();
    // Some stuff happens after the function
    r
}

struct Contrived {
    value: u32,
}

impl Contrived {
    fn func(&'static mut self) {
        run_in_special_state(|| foo(self));

        self.value = 6;
    }
}

static mut INSTANCE: Contrived = Contrived { value: 4 };

fn main() {
    unsafe { INSTANCE.func() };
}
```

Here's what you'll get when you run that in the playground:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `self`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:19:30
   |
19 |         run_in_special_state(|| foo(self));
   |                              ^^     ---- `self` is borrowed here
   |                              |
   |                              may outlive borrowed value `self`
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `self` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
19 |         run_in_special_state(move || foo(self));
   |                              ^^^^^^^
```

I know that the `FnOnce` is going to be called before `run_in_special_state` exits. I believe this also means that the closure will not outlive the current function (`func`?), since it (the closure) will be executed and discarded before the current function (`func`) exits. How can I communicate this to the borrow checker? Is something else going on here? I've noticed that if I drop the `'static` requirement on `foo` that the error disappears.

I can't do the suggested fix, since I need to use `self` after `run_in_special_state` is called.

Answer (score 1):

The signatures of those functions:

- `fn foo(_: &'static Contrived)`
- `fn func (&'static mut self)`

require references which borrow their values for the duration of entire program, while you need references which borrow their values just long enough.

Remove `'static` and the program will compile:

```
fn foo(_: &Contrived) {}

fn run_in_special_state<F, R>(f: F) -> R
where
    F: FnOnce() -> R,
{
    // Some stuff happens before the function
    let r = f();
    // Some stuff happens after the function
    r
}

struct Contrived {
    value: u32,
}

impl Contrived {
    fn func(&mut self) {
        run_in_special_state(|| foo(self));

        self.value = 6;
    }
}

static mut INSTANCE: Contrived = Contrived { value: 4 };

fn main() {
    unsafe { INSTANCE.func() };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=71360cb0aa5b0c3b212fcaa8a597ab3e&version=stable)

`&'static T` isn't just an address of a variable, it bears additional semantics. If you want to use it as a unique identifier, you'll probably be better off creating a type, which retains only the uniqueness of the address and don't borrow the value:

```
mod key {
    use super::Contrived;

    #[derive(Debug, Hash)]
    pub struct ContrivedId(usize);

    impl ContrivedId {
        pub fn new(r: &'static Contrived) -> Self {
            ContrivedId(r as *const _ as usize)
        }
    }
}

use key::ContrivedId;

fn foo(_: ContrivedId) {}

fn run_in_special_state<F, R>(f: F) -> R
where
    F: FnOnce() -> R,
{
    // Some stuff happens before the function
    let r = f();
    // Some stuff happens after the function
    r
}

pub struct Contrived {
    value: u32,
}

impl Contrived {
    fn func(&mut self, id: ContrivedId) {
        run_in_special_state(|| foo(id));

        self.value = 6;
    }
}

static mut INSTANCE: Contrived = Contrived { value: 4 };

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let id = ContrivedId::new(&INSTANCE);
        INSTANCE.func(id)
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c01f0f4bdfb15a1fbc84469625f09501&version=stable)

Comment: `ContrivedId` might as well take a `&'static T`